# Wired and Wireless Network Duplication

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet

Running into an issue when some of our client's have their laptop's connected via the wired ethernet network aswell as on the WLAN of the same network.

There is know issues caused to the end clients.. BUT! Being a Managed Services Engineer i get pretty over the alerts that come through on our reports for machine's with the same hostname on the same network!
We are not going to remove this monitoring because it does help a lot with detecting and stopping inferior users and things like that.

So basically.. Question is, is there a way in Windows (third party programs welcome) to disable the wireless network when a wired network is connected and operational.. I know that Windows automticaly 'prefers' the wired network, however they are still both connected and therfore there is duplicate hostnames on the same network.
Could also have stupid issues with DNS and things like that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Methods for doing this vary by device manufacturer.

- There may be an option in the OEM's wireless networking utility.
- There may be an option in the BIOS, if the card is built-in.
- Windows XP or later:  There may be an option on the Advanced tab, in the Properties page of the WiFi card, in Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So there is no clearcut standard way of doing it?

Comment: @Dave - The closest to a "standard" way, would be the third option in my post.  This presumes you're using Windows XP or above.